# ScrollView com RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Como faço para o `RelativeLayout` ocupar toda a altura da tela dentro da `ScrollView`? (tentei `wrap_contet` mas como tenho anuncio AdMob ela dá erro com o botão)

Codigo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context="alcoolougasolina.aplicativo.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Descubra qual combustivel é mais vantajoso abastecer."
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />


            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7380991228143623/3071936395"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Preço Gasolina:"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:text="@string/edt1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Preço Álcool:"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:text="@string/edt2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bt1"
                android:id="@+id/Calcular"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:onClick="calculo"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que deixar que seu `ScrollView` ocupe todo espaço da tela alterando sua altura para `match_parent`, aí sim assim todo conteúdo que estiver dentro

> **match_parent**: A View deve ocupar o espaço igual ao da sua Parent View
>   (View Pai). Em qualquer dimensão(altura e/ou largura)
>
> **fill_parent**: Mesma função do match_parent, porém era utilizada no
>   android 2.1, quando foi feito o update para o 2.3, foi descontinuada em
>   uso do match_parent.
>
> **wrap_content**: A View deve ocupar apenas o espaço que necessitar(altura
>   e/ou largura) para exibir suas informações no layout.

Os atributos da ScrollView ficariam assim, ocupando todo espaço tando na vertical, quanto na horizontal:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]